# "Command not found" error after installing Python 3.3 on OS X

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

I was using Python 2.7 as it was installed on my Mac by default. I tried to update it to python 3.4. In the process I deleted 2.7 via the command line. 
I installed python 3.4 using an installer but I am still getting following error:

> python: Command not found

I checked and found that this folder does not exist:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4

I followed the instructions on [this website](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/) to update Python. Everything went well until step 5 but was unsuccessful for step 6 and 7.

I am in a complete mess as I have deleted the older version, Python 2.7. How can I fix my Python installation to solve the error and use Python 3.4?

Comment: OS X *itself* relies on Python 2.7. Where exactly did you delete Python from? If from `/usr/bin`, you'll likely have to reinstall your machine from backup.

Comment: Wow, that blog article indeed advocates removing the system Python. **That is one huge stupid mistake**. Don't mess with the system Python. There is no need to go to such drastic steps and **breaks OS functionality**. There is some monumentally bad advice in that blog post.

Comment: That article is indeed plain wrong - never mess with a system Python installation.

Comment: Python versions can happily live side by side. I have 8 different Python versions installed on my laptop, for example. The version bundled with OS X comes pre-installed with 3rd party libraries OS X services coded in Python rely on. You cannot just replace it with a newer version, and there is no need to even try.

Comment: When you get it up and running again I might install Python through Homebrew. I have had good luck with it in the past and it installs it in a way that makes upgrading and removal easy should you need to.

Comment: I checked usr/bin if i have deleted it from there. but it seems i haven't. Following is the list of folders that is in this folder                                                               pydoc
diff3    pydoc2.5
diffstat   pydoc2.6
dig    pydoc2.7
dirname    python
diskhits   python-config
dispqlen.d   python2.5
ditto    python2.5-config
dns-sd    python2.6
dnsctl    python2.6-config
dprofpp    python2.7
dprofpp5.12   python2.7-config
drutil    pythonw
dscacheutil   pythonw2.5
dscl    pythonw2.6
dserr    pythonw2.7

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: the blog post also advocates deleting stuff in `/System`; don't ever do that.

Comment: my mac is still up and running. Will there be a problem when i restart system..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help ..
i tried brew install as mentioned in your comment. I am getting following warning now:
Failed to import the site module
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

how should i work around this.. any idea..?

many thanks!

Comment: What folders exist in  `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`?

Comment: Also: Your title says 3.3 but your question and tags say 3.4. Double check which one it is and edit your question to be consistent, please.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the several users who have commented that it's a bad idea to alter or remove the system's Python installation, it looks like the problem here is that you followed the steps given in the linked blog post to upgrade *from version 2.x to a more recent version 2.x*. Note where it says (emphasis mine):

> To read about how to upgrade to Python 3.3, **jump to the very bottom of
>   this post.**

Steps 1 through 7 in the blog post show how to upgrade the system Python from 2.7.1 to 2.7.3. While it would be fine to install them side-by-side instead—leaving you free to alter or delete *your* version without breaking the system version—you probably wouldn't run into trouble upgrading the system version from patch 1 to patch 3 of the same minor release.

However, **[Python 3 is not backwards-compatible with Python 2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)**. If your system version of Python is 2.x, replacing it with version 3.x just won't work; the system *depends* on having 2.x available. Note that the section at the bottom of the blog post titled "Updating to Python 3.3" does not remove Python 2.7:

```
rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

What it does instead is remove any existing installation of *the version to be upgraded*, in this case Python 3.3, to avoid a `Directory not empty` error when trying to move the upgraded version into the system folder.

You need a working version of Python 2 in your system folder. If you want to use Python 3, you need a separate installation entirely. Rather than backtracking the steps of the guide in reverse order, you may be able to simply start again at step 1, but this time download and install Python 2 instead of Python 3, but you will need to make sure you understand what each step does, looking up shell commands if necessary, because it sounds like you've already made some modifications you *don't* understand in trying to adapt the wrong section to apply to Python 3.

For example, you might have changed the second command from step 2 from

```
sudo mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

to

```
sudo mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

when you were trying to use this step to "upgrade" from 2 to 3; otherwise, you would have gotten a `No such file or directory` error. If this is the case, you won't have a `2.7` folder to remove in the very first step because you already removed it the first time around and didn't replace it.

Comment: a big Thanks friend. I was able to follow your instructions in detail. I successfully installed python 2.7 again.  
Now i wil install Python3.4 again ..  
A big Thanks again!